# size date not saving in cartitem model but the product is saving.. Any solution how to save the size data also?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-views

**views.py**

```
def add_to_cart(request, pk):

    variant = request.GET.get('variant')
    
    product = Product.objects.get(pk =pk)
    user = request.user
    cart , _ = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user = user, is_paid = False)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart = cart , product = product ,)

    if variant:
        variant = request.GET.get('variant')
        size_variant = SizeVariant.objects.get(size_name = variant)
        color_variant = ColorVariant.objects.get(color_name = variant)
        cart_item.color_variant = color_variant
        cart_item.size_variant = size_variant
        cart_item.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

**models.py**

```py
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color_variant = models.ForeignKey(ColorVariant, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    size_variant = models.ForeignKey(SizeVariant, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

[image]

[22/Aug/2022 16:17:38] "GET /account/add_to_cart/1/?variant= HTTP/1.1" 302 0

**XXX**

16049.0

```
class SizeVariant(models.Model):
    size_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.size_name
```

------------------------------------------------------------///////

Comment: Can you share your SizeVariand model and what is  `request.GET.get('variant')` returns?

Comment: variant return is size variant  or color variant

Comment: You are calling it with empty variant parameter based on the log. The if variant then does not run.

Comment: @Dipankar are size variant and color variant the same?

Comment: @enesislam yes same

Comment: Check it through `print(color_variant)`  and `print(size_variant)` does they return something? Also see `print(variant)` does it contain something from GET request?

Comment: @SunderamDubey yes is returning.. My question is see there xxx is the size that I priented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact problem, but I'd recommend to use [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), and also creating instance directly using [`create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#create) instead of first creating then updating, so try below view:

```py
def add_to_cart(request, pk):

    variant = request.GET.get('variant')
    
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=pk)
    user = request.user
    cart , _ = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user = user, is_paid = False)

    if variant:
        size_variant = get_object_or_404(SizeVariant,size_name=variant)
        color_variant = get_object_or_404(ColorVariant,color_name=variant)
        CartItem.objects.create(cart = cart, product = product,color_variant=color_variant,size_variant=size_variant)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the id of variant instead of name. Just send the id with ajax like how you got the same object's name.

```py
def add_to_cart(request, pk):

    variant = request.GET.get('variant')
    
    product = Product.objects.get(pk =pk)
    user = request.user
    cart , _ = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user = user, is_paid = False)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart = cart , product = product ,)

    if variant:
        variant_id = request.GET.get('variant_id')
        size_variant = SizeVariant.objects.get(id=variant_id)
        color_variant = ColorVariant.objects.get(id=variant_id)
        cart_item.color_variant = color_variant
        cart_item.size_variant = size_variant
        cart_item.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

I can help you out about ajax if you can share the ajax side of this page.

Comment: <script>
 function get_correct_price(size){
  window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?size='+size
 }
 
</script>